# What path for Heroku Rails 4 Assets pipeline in css files

Tags: jquery, css, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I running a Rails 4 App on Heroku with custom Jquery-ui css and image assets. I used rail's asset:precomile and the css/js files work fine on Heroku. The problem I have are the background-image url in the css files of the custom jquery-ui.

I know they are located in assets/jquery-ui/(orginial-filename)-(rails digest #).(png jpg...), and it would work if I manually set each file to their exact path on Heroku, but there must be an easier way. As of right now all my css image file path are prefixed with /assets/(imagefilename).

---

Update: Actually it's not a conflict between the jquery-ui-rails gem and my custom jquery-ui css. The problem has something to do with how Sprocket compiles the scss or sass.

```
 .ui-icon
   width: 16px
   height: 16px
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png')

 .ui-widget-content .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png')

 .ui-widget-header .ui-icon, .ui-state-default .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_b83400_256x240.png')

 .ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png')

 .ui-state-active .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_8c291d_256x240.png')

 .ui-state-highlight .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_3572ac_256x240.png')

 .ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_fbdb93_256x240.png')
```

What's happening to me is this... everything gets compile into application.css/gz. However 
     .ui-icon
       width: 16px
       height: 16px
       background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png')

```
 .ui-widget-content .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png')
```

image-url gets compile into url(/assets/....) works fine. But everything below

```
 .ui-widget-header .ui-icon, .ui-state-default .ui-icon
   background-image: image-url('jquery-ui/ui-icons_b83400_256x240.png')
```

all image-url gets convert to url(/images/orginial_filename).... which doesn't work.

---

Haha... never mind I figured out why this is happening. That's because the precompiler is not loading the vendor/assets/images folder. Just had to include it in the array. I guess the precompiler sets image-url to url(images/default_filename) if it doesn't find the compile image asset.

Answer (score 0):

## When using Gems that hook into the asset pipeline, you basically have 3 options.

From *easiest* to *hardest*.

### Options 1: Install the gem and use it without customization.

- `gem 'jquery/ui-rails'` in Gemfile
- `$ bundle install`
- `rake assets:precompile`
- Enjoy.

### Option 2: Install the library manually and don't install the gem.

- Download **jquery-ui** from their site.
- Copy it to **/app/assets/jquery-ui**
- `rake assets:precompile`
- Enjoy.

### Option 3: Install the gem then override the default with custom assets.

**WARNING:** Javascript/Stylesheet `require` nightmare.

- `gem 'jquery-ui-rails`` in Gemfile
- `bundle install`
- Customize the library by adding asset files in app/assets/stylesheets and app/assets/javascripts
- Add the appropriate `require`s in **/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css** that include the stock jquery-ui files first then require your custom files to override the defaults.
- Repeat previous step for javascripts.
- Enjoy.

**Notes:** You can do Option 2 and edit the stock jquery-ui to suit your needs but a lot of people consider this impure.  There are advantages to keeping the clean jquery-ui files separate from your customizations I guess.

This applies to all the asset gems like Bootstrap, etc...

---

And don't forget...

In your CSS files (assuming they are **SASS**, aka `application.css.scss`), you can use

```
image-url('jquery-ui/whatever.jpg');
```

and that will be translated to

```
url('/assets/jquery-ui/whatever-<hash>.jpg');
```

in your compiled CSS document.  You can use that with `background-image`, etc...

Comment: thanks this works but for some odd reason it compiles the image path twice. Once to url('/assets/...) once to url('/images/....) which is causing the problem I don't know if this is because of the jquery-ui-rails gem

Comment: @Steve007 If you have the **jquery-ui-rails** gem installed, running `rake assets:precompile` basically copies the original **jquery-ui** files from the gem location on your system to `/public/assets/jquery-ui`.  If you also have **jquery-ui** files in `/app/assets/...` it's possible that `rake assets:precompile` will stick those in `/public/images`.

Answer (score 0):

Haha... never mind I figured out why this is happening. That's because the precompiler is not loading the vendor/assets/images folder. Just had to include it in the array. I guess the precompiler sets image-url to url(images/default_filename) if it doesn't find the compile image asset.